# how can i refresh page without submit using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have DropDownList in layout page and in other pages users can submit the forms, I want the page to automatically update when the user changes the DropDownList, But the page is automatically submit when the user changes it.

```js
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#Services").change(function (event) {
                var Servicecookie = getCookie("sid_Cookie");
                if (Servicecookie != null) {
                    setCookie("sid_Cookie", $(this).val());
                    $("#selectedService").html($("#Services option:selected").text());
                }
                else {
                    setCookie("sid_Cookie", $(this).val());
                    $("#selectedService").html($("#Services option:selected").text());
                }

                location.reload();

            });
        });

        function getCookie(key) {
            var keyValue = document.cookie.match('(^|;) ?' + key + '=([^;]*)(;|$)');
            return keyValue ? keyValue[2] : null;
        }
        function setCookie(key, value) {
            var expires = new Date();
            expires.setTime(expires.getTime() + (1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
            document.cookie = key + '=' + value + ';expires=' + expires.toUTCString();
        }
    </script>
```

Resolved:

I first get the page URL address and then go to it.

```js
var url = window.location.href;
window.location.href = url;
```

with this code, i call [HttpGet] action.

Comment: Your script doesn't indicate that a form submit would occur on dropdown change. Have you checked if you have not tied any other scripts to your .change()?

Comment: You stopped a page mysteriously submitting by setting `window.location.href` somewhere? None of this question makes any sense

Answer (score 0):

You can use event.preventDefault().

If this method is called, the default action of the event will not be triggered.

For example, clicked anchors will not take the browser to a new URL. We can use event.isDefaultPrevented() to determine if this method has been called by an event handler that was triggered by this event.

Please refer : https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Comment: I did it, but again the page is posted. To understand what I mean, you can post(submit) a page in browser and hit the f5 key in your browser.

for example in Firefox alert this message:
To display this page, Firefox must send information that will repeat any action (such as a search or order confirmation) that was performed earlier.

Comment: There is no submit anywhere in your posted code. You must be missing some code

Comment: I explained in my question that the pages are being sent. I did not think that you needed HTML to send pages, so I did not write the HTML code in the question.